# ng-contextmenu is not working in angular 13

Tags: angular13

```
After upgrading Angular version 12 to 13, typescript version is also updated to 4.6.4,
In typescipt 4.x version ClientRect is depercated and in our code we are using clientrect for 
contextmenu that is supported in angular 12 . In angular 13 our code is not working for ngx- 
contextmenu.

Below code is used in application :
 const offset = this.getOffset(this.divElement.nativeElement);
    const anchorElement: any = {};
     anchorElement.getBoundingClientRect = () : ClientRect=> ({
      bottom: offset.top + $event.clientY,
      height: 0,
      left: offset.left + $event.clientX,
      right: offset.left + $event.clientX,
      top: offset.top + $event.clientY,
      width: 0
    });
```

Tried : In above code clientRect is deprecated , so we removed clientRect from code :
now the code is fine , but after doing right click for context menu below issue is coming in
console.
issue  : ngx-contextmenu - this.overlay.position(...) connectedTo is not a function

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.